# Firebase Database - Set rules for users in the database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Now I have these rules

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users":{
            "$uid":{
                ".write": "$uid == auth.uid",
                ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

When authorizing, I write data to the database along this path[image]

Further in the application, I want to display all user emails, but nothing is displayed.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        listData = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        getDatafromDB();
    }

    private void getDatafromDB(){
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (listData.size() > 0) listData.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.child("users").getChildren()){
                    User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    listData.add(user.email);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }
}
```

If I write the initial rules,

```
{
    "rules": {

                ".write": "false",
                ".read": "true"

    }
}
```

then everything is displayed. Based on this, I conclude that I am setting the rules incorrectly. How to do it right?

Comment: the `android-studio` tag is only used when your question is regarding the IDE, just because you're using android studio doesn't mean you should add it as a tag to your question, so i've removed it :)

Comment: ok, now I will know

Comment: no problem, it's a common mistake, goodluck in finding an answer, unfortunately i can't help with that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting your rules as follows:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users":{
            "$uid":{
                ".write": "$uid == auth.uid",
                ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

a user can only read the database node corresponding to his/her user UID. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#the_auth_variable) for more details.

---

You don't detail which exact access rights you want to implement (All users can read the entire `users` node? Only the authenticated users can read the entire `users` node? etc...) but you need to adapt your rule accordingly.

---

PS: Also, don't forget that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#rules-not-filters).

---

#### Update following your comment

Yes, if you want to check, in your rules that the user has verified he/she has access to the email address you would do `... auth.token.email_verified == true`. See this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#identify_users) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I got it already. All users must be able to read and write to the Users branch.
To do this, I need to set rules something like this so that verified users can edit the branch? 
"auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true"

Comment: Thx for "rules are not filters" link. Now I understood my mistake

Comment: sorry, i forgot